# Save form data Yii2

Tags: forms, yii2, save

I have a question. Let's say we have a model smth like this:

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 */
 class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {
     public static function tableName()
     {
         return 'user';
     }

     public function rules()
     {
         return [
             // some rules for fields
         ];
     }

     public function attributeLabels()
     {
         return [
             // some attributes
         ];
     }
```

Now I want to create additional form model for update ONLY (for example) first_name. So I created next form model:

```
 class UpdateUserFirstNameForm extends Model
 {
     public $first_name

     public function rules()
     {
         return [
             // some rules for first_name
         ];
     }
```

And the question is - How I can save this form? What I have to write in controller?

Comment: Your `user` table, has a field named `first_name`?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can see that in a @property to user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create another attribute in your `UpdateUserFirstNameForm` for the User's `id`, let's say `id_user`. Then, create in your form an `activeHiddenField` with User's id (along with the text input for the User's first name).

Now in the controller, you load the post content into your model, find the user by id and update the `User` model with the new first name:

```
$model = new UpdateUserFirstNameForm();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request()->post() and $model->validate()) {
  $user = User::findOne($model->id_user);
  if ($user == null)
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  $user->first_name = $model->first_name;
  $user->save();
}
```

Comment: OK, Another case: in my `user` model in rules has a `last_name` => required. And when I call `save` method to update `first_name` field - will be error, because `save` method calls `validate` method.

Comment: But if you find your User from you db and returns a record, the data should be correct, right?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to create another model UpdateUserFirstNameForm when you have one, you can make whatever inside your controller. Update, save or delete. And

```
class UpdateUserFirstNameForm extends Model
```

is used just for validation, there is no access to db